# ImportError: cannot import name 'EndpointConfig'

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

from rasa_core.utils import EndpointConfig

ImportError: cannot import name 'EndpointConfig'

Rasa Core version:
0.8.2

Python version:
3

Can  any one help me to solve ,

```
interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter('./models/nlu/default/weathernlu')

action_endpoint = EndpointConfig(url="http://localhost:5055/webhook")

agent = Agent.load('./models/dialogue', interpreter=interpreter, action_endpoint=action_endpoint)

rasa_core.run.serve_application(agent ,channel='cmdline')
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the changelog ([Link to Changelog](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#0100---2018-07-17)) `EndpointConfig` was added with Rasa Core version `0.10.0` However, you are using `0.8.2`.

I recommend updating to the latest version (`0.11.12`) in general because there were a lot of changes with Rasa Core version `0.11.0`. Migrating to the latest version might be a bit of a pain when you have a large project, but provides you more and more mature features.